# Collect checked checkboxes by custom parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

What is the correct way to collect checked checkboxes by custom parameter in it?

```
<input class="4input" id="checkbox_1" name="checkbox_name" is_interest_rate="1" type="checkbox" value="1.0">

<input class="4input" id="checkbox_2" name="checkbox_name" is_interest_rate="1" type="checkbox" value="1.0">
```

As you can see there is a custom `parameter`called `is_interest_rate`.

I need to collect all checked checkboxes where `is_interest_rate` is 1.

I know how to collect them by the `name`:

```
$('input[name="checkbox_name"]:checked');
```

But how to do it with custom parameter?

P.S Sorry if this is a duplicated question, couldn't find any similar problem.

Thanks!

Comment: The syntax is identical to the selector you've got, just change `name` to `is_interest_rate` and `checkbox_name` to `1`. ***However*** it's worth noting that you should not be inventing your own non-standard attributes. If you want to store custom metadata then use a data attribute, eg `data-is-interest-rate="1"`. Make sure you amend the selector for this, though.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thank you, but unfortunately i can't change `name`. This html is only for the preview. In original way it has more complicated `id and name` and they are uniq for each record. Okay, if i will go with data attribute, i should use smth like this => $('input[data="is_interest_rate"]:checked');?

Comment: No, `$('input[data-is-interest-rate="1"]:checked');`

Answer (score 0):

Then you Rory McCrossan for the solution.

```
$('input[data-is-interest-rate="1"]:checked');
```